# Functional Constrained Optimization Python Incorrect Answer

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I'm trying to minimize a functional (integral of a function), given constraints

```
def s(y,a,b,c,d):
    v = [1, y, y**2, y**3]
    alpha = [a, b, c, d]
    q = np.inner(v,alpha)
    return -q*np.exp(-q)
def p(y,a,b,c,d):
    v = [1, y, y**2, y**3]
    alpha = [a, b, c, d]
    q = np.inner(v,alpha)
    return np.exp(-q)

def Q(u):
    a, b, c, d = u
    d = integrate.quad(lambda y: s(y,a,b,c,d), 0, 1)
    return d[0]
cons = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun' : integrate.quad(lambda y: p(y,a,b,c,d), 0,     1)[0]-1},
    {'type': 'eq', 'fun' : integrate.quad(lambda y: (p(y,a,b,c,d)*y), 0, 1)[0]-0.483523521402009},
    {'type': 'eq', 'fun' : integrate.quad(lambda y: (p(y,a,b,c,d)*y**2), 0, 1)[0]-0.300458990347083},
    {'type': 'eq', 'fun' : integrate.quad(lambda y: (p(y,a,b,c,d)*y**3), 0, 1)[0]-0.209996591802522})
res = minimize(Q, x0 = (0, 0, 0, 0), method='BFGS', constraints=cons)
print(res)
```

I get an output

```
fun: -0.36787942624169967
 hess_inv: array([[  17.98311921,  -49.74794121,    2.50822967,   36.21942131],
   [ -49.74794121,  191.70720321,  -23.14586623, -158.65310285],
   [   2.50822967,  -23.14586623,    8.1640543 ,   25.72129091],
   [  36.21942131, -158.65310285,   25.72129091,  142.59127393]])
  jac: array([ -3.54647636e-06,  -1.94460154e-06,  -1.75461173e-06,
     3.24100256e-07])
  message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
 nfev: 126*
  *nit: 19
 njev: 21
   status: 0
  success: True
    x: array([ 0.99920744,  0.0092224 , -0.02276881,  0.0150456 ])**
```

However using this array of X, does not satisfy the constraint

```
x = (0.99920744,  0.0092224 , -0.02276881,  0.0150456)
integrate.quad(lambda y: p(y,x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3]), 0, 1)[0]
```

0.3678829742546207

which is not 1, as specifically stated in the constraint. How is it claiming convergence when it clearly has not converged?

Comment: For starters: ```BFGS``` does not allow constraints. Not sure how scipy is behaving with your call. [docs:](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html): ```Constraints definition (only for COBYLA and SLSQP)```

Comment: Your `fun` values appear to be numbers, rather than functions. They need to be functions.

Comment: @sascha under the SLSQP method I get this error `/in _minimize_slsqp(func, x0, args, jac, bounds, constraints, maxiter, ftol, iprint, disp, eps, callback, **unknown_options)
    309     # Set the parameters that SLSQP will need
    310     # meq, mieq: number of equality and inequality constraints
--> 311     meq = sum(map(len, [atleast_1d(c['fun'](x, *c['args'])) for c in cons['eq']]))
    312     mieq = sum(map(len, [atleast_1d(c['fun'](x, *c['args'])) for c in cons['ineq']]))
    313     # m = The total number of constraints

TypeError: 'float' object is not callable`

Comment: @user2357112 the fun values should be functions in terms of a,b,c,d

Comment: With this error you now (pretty much) know these constraints weren't used before. Now it's time to process user2357112's comments. The docs will help If you are not able to repair it, add an example we can run.